# EntityFramework Include ThenInclude Multiple Super Slow

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have below code with multiple .Include and .ThenInclude.

```
var query = _postUserRepository.TableNoTracking;

query = query.Where(x => x.User.Name.Contains(name));
query = query.Where(x => x.User.Email.Contains(email));
query = query.Where(x => x.JobPostId == jobPostId);
query = query.Where(x => x.JobPost.ExpiresAt > expiredDate);
query = query.Where(x => x.JobPost.UserId == userId);
query = query.Include(x => x.User)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.Languages);
query = query.Include(x => x.User)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.Skills);
query = query.Include(x => x.User)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.Educations);
query = query.Include(x => x.User)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.Resumes;
query = query.Include(x => x.User)
                .ThenInclude(y => y.Talent);

var list = query.Take(20).ToList()
```

I think the issue is because multiple .ThenInclude.

How to fix the issue?

Comment: ...also your query is non-SARGable because you're using `Contains` for a substring match. That's always going to be slow.

Comment: ...why are you doing `Include(x=>x.User)` **six times**?!

Comment: Use `AsSplitQuery()`. [Single vs. Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)